# Python Split Regex not split what I need

Tags: python, regex

I have this in my file

```py
import re

sample = """Name: @s
Owner: @a[tag=Admin]"""

target = r"@[sae](\[[\w{}=, ]*\])?"
regex = re.split(target, sample)

print(regex)
```

I want to split all words that start with `@`, so like this:
`["Name: ", "@s", "\nOwner: ", "@a[tag=Admin]"]`

But instead it give this:
`['Name: ', None, '\nOwner: ', '[tag=Admin]', '']`

How to seperating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` here:

```py
sample = """Name: @s
Owner: @a[tag=Admin]"""
parts = re.findall(r'@\w+(?:\[.*?\])?|\s*\S+\s*', sample)
print(parts)  # ['Name: ', '@s', '\nOwner: ', '@a[tag=Admin]']
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
@\w+          a tag @some_tag
(?:\[.*?\])?  followed by an optional [...] term
|             OR
\s*\S+\s*     any other non whitespace term,
              including optional whitespace on both sides
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the requirements correctly you could do that as follows:

```
import re
```

```
s = """Name: @s
Owner: @a[tag=Admin]
"""
```

```
rgx = r'(?=@.*)|(?=\r?\n[^@\r\n]*)'
```

```
re.split(rgx, s)
  #=> ['Name: ', '@s', '\nOwner: ', '@a[tag=Admin]\n']
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwEEDR/ZxiyKZNkW7cCaHxAnqApkLAEANmGiYBK3j3OKv/Fr9822unc@8pl50bcgCoaFApdfM5XNBWuH8osMivzUdzfeZEG8gAwPGQl4dxMXae9E/qeHG0PqxjR9ukB4DCidrIYa7lnQTxOGHVGnr/Aw)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?=         # begin a positive lookahead
  @.*       # match '@' followed by >= 0 chars other than line terminators
)           # end positive lookahead
|           # or
(?=         # begin a positive lookahead
  \r?\n     # match a line terminator
  [^@\r\n]* # match >= 0 characters other than '@' and line terminators 
)           # end positive lookahead
```

Notice that matches are zero-width.

Comment: Helping you get a T-shirt +1.

Comment: @Tim, I similarly helped you toward that 0.5M golf ring.

Answer (score 0):

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) expects the regular expression to match the delimiters in the string. It only returns the parts of the delimiters which are [captured](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions#group-extraction). In the case of your regex, that's only the part between the brackets, if present.

If you want the whole delimiter to show up in the list, put parentheses around the whole regex:

```py
target = r"(@[sae](\[[\w{}=, ]*\])?)"
```

But you are probably better off not capturing the interior group. You can change it to a non-capturing group by using `(?:…)` instead of `(…)`:

```py
target = r"(@[sae](?:\[[\w{}=, ]*\])?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your output, you keep the `[tag=Admin]` as that part is in a capture group, and using split can also return empty strings.

Another option is to be specific about the allowed data format, and instead of split capture the parts in 2 groups.

```
(\s*\w+:\s*)(@[sae](?:\[[\w{}=, ]*])?)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\s*\w+:\s*` Match 1+ word characters and `:` between optional whitespace chars
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `@[sae]` Match `@` followed by either `s` `a` `e`
  - `(?:\[[\w{}=, ]*])?` Optionally match `[...]`
- `)` Close group

Example code:

```
import re

sample = """Name: @s
Owner: @a[tag=Admin]"""
target = r"(\s*\w+:\s*)(@[sae](?:\[[\w{}=, ]*])?)"

listOfTuples = re.findall(target, sample)
lst = [s for tpl in listOfTuples for s in tpl]
print(lst)
```

Output

```
['Name: ', '@s', '\nOwner: ', '@a[tag=Admin]']
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/amNZ52/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2qhwqr).